# SharePoint Licensing using FBA

Tags: forms-authentication, licensing

I've a remaining question in my head... If i use FBA for authenticate my users, does it changes the licensing volume of my SharePoint farm?

Using FBA my users are almost SQL Server side and could not be in Active directory right?
So that might change the CAL for a 2010 SharePoint server no? Does Microsoft has plan for this?

Sorry if the question is a non-sense, but I really appreciate to get answers, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010: How to Buy](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/default.aspx)

> You can use SharePoint 2010 to set up intranet, extranet, and Internet
>   sites.  Intranet sites are licensed using a Server/CAL (Client Access
>   License) model.  SharePoint Server 2010 is required for each running
>   instance of the software, and **CALs are required for each person or
>   device accessing a SharePoint Server**.  Extranet and Internet sites are
>   licensed using a Server-only model—no CALs are required.

So it really doesn't matter how your users are authenticated.